# Which C++ specification started to support std::vector

Tags: c++

I would like to know which C++ specification started to support std::vector? Also, how can we check (through preprocessor macros) if this specification is supported by the C++ compiler?

Comment: `std::vector` is there since `C++03`. You can change compiler's documentation on which standard it supports.

Comment: @vahancho, I believe it was in C++98.

Comment: @NicolasIceberg, I appreciate the knowledge of the olds :) , the first international standard is C++98, there is none before.

Comment: The vast majority of implementations released 2000 or later that claim compliance with the C++ standard or later will practically support `std::vector`. Practically, before 2000, vendors were still catching up with the ratified standard (and still were for some features after that, with at least one vendor notable for claiming compliance but not delivering a compliant product, but you mostly can be confident `std::vector` was supported reasonably early). You may get lucky with some compilers/libraries that predate 2000,but I wouldn't bet on it - even if they claim ANSI/ISO C++ compliance.

Answer (score 9):

### Introduced in C++98, part of the Working Draft at least since WG21/N0545 September 1994

[Chapter 23](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/lib-containers.html), [lib.containers], of the

- [WG21/N0545: Working Paper for Draft Proposed International Standard for Information Systems-- Programming Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/coversheet.html)

paper from 20 September 1994 (informally [*September 1994 C++ Working Paper*](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/)), particularly the [[lib.vector]](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/lib-containers.html#lib.vector) section is, afaik, the first formal paper/draft to introduce (`std::`)`vector`, along with a number of other familiar container classes.

The annually updated *C++ Working Paper* was what would eventually become the first C++ ISO standard release, [*ISO/IEC 14882:1998 - Programming languages — C++*](https://www.iso.org/standard/25845.html), which included STL and its initial set of container classes.

### First mention: November 1991 meeting in Dallas

As everything about the language can be considered to have been in a draft/evolution stage up until the first ISO release in 1998, the containers are likely to have been discussed and proposed even earlier. Possibly the chapter above was part, in some form, already in WG21/N0100 (*Working Paper for Draft Proposed American National Standard for Information Systems - Programming Languages* from 1992), but I haven't been able to find a copy of this reference. The [WG21/N0110](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1992/WG21%201992/X3J16_92-0042%20WG21_N0119.pdf) *Report from the Library working group* from 3 March 1992 indeed refers to a *Containers* section and the work with it being started/considered already in 1991 [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### Progress Report - November 1991 - March 1992
>
> [...]
>
> ***What is the group working on***
>
> While the language portion of C++ has had over 10 years' evolution and refinement, the standard library has had much less time to develop. **The availability of templates** and exceptions, **only recently added to the language**, has a **significant impact on the design of libraries** for C++. [...]
>
> ***Current focus***
>
> The current focus of the Library group remains as it has since the July, 1990 meeting in Seattle. The November, 1991 meeting in Dallas **added consideration of simple container classes**.
>
> [...]
>
> *18.5 Containers*
>
> Reviewing available libraries **revealed a small set of common classes**. Strings were most frequent, and are already in the C++ library (18.4). Array and bit set classes were next most frequent, and appeared "easy" to specify.
>
> The design approach would emphasize Concrete Data Types **using templates. Proposals for container classes will add a new section to the library portion of the standard**.
>
> [...]
>
> **Open issues from last time**
>
> [...]
>
> *18.5 Containers*
>
> [...] agreed to allow the Library working group to pursue specification of **two new components**. [...]
>
> The BitSet component [...]. The Array component will described self-describing arrays that avoid some of the problems associated with the array derived type define in the language.
>
> [...]

This first referral to the work of *"The Array [STL container] component"*, later (branched out into) the `DynArray` component (see below) was what would eventually become `std::vector`.

### WG21/N0083: Generic Dynamic Arrays in C++

The paper

- [WG21/N0083: Generic Dynamic Arrays](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1992/WG21%201992/X3J16_92-0005%20WG21_N0083.pdf)

from 4 January 1992 is a proposal for a ***generic dynamic array class*** named `DynArray`, with an alternative name proposal as `vector`:

> #### Generic Dynamic Arrays in C++
>
> [...]
>
> **2. Proposal for a generic dynamic array class**
>
> [...] The name "DynArray" for this class is selected as "array" is a built-in type in C++ **and the alternative "vector"** may be expected to be a mathematical class (and would have different member functions). [...]

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` will work with c++98 standard.
Maybe it was added earlier.

That answer was based on [that](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) site.

Comment: OP asked which specification added it, not which standard it works with.

Answer (score 3):

Stl was added in 1998 in c++98 version

[All c++ version description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQpTg.png)

what new features are added in every c++ vesion